# Django : how to define a unique slug for an abstract model and its children?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have an abstract model that contains common fields of my models but how to define a unique slug because I can't make query on abstract model but only on its subclasses?

I'm looking for a clean and simple method without mentioning the name of subclasses manually..

```
class MainModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('slug'), unique=True, max_length=150)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', verbose_name=_('category'))

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # define unique slug for ChildModel1, ChildModel2

class ChildModel1(MainModel):
    active = models.BooleanField()

class ChildModel2(MainModel):
    content = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the model's [`verbose_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.verbose_name):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # fill in make_slug yourself
    self.slug = make_slug(self._meta.verbose_name)
```